# ExoPlayer not playing from file

Tags: android, exoplayer

I have a `ExoPlayer` set up with `HlsRendererBuilder`.
So far I have been passing it an Uri to a `m3u8` stream file on the server. It is working great. 
Now I have an option to download the video to your phone and play it from storage. I have successfully downloaded the file from the given link, stored it in the app private folder. All permissions to access external storage requested and approved.
In this case I am passing an Uri from file which I have downloaded.
Uri looks like this: `file:///storage/emulated/0/video/file.mp4`. When I start the playback the file is never loaded. I do not get any exception or error in the log. Can anyone help me to suggest an approach? I will provide snippet of codes if needed, but not sure which part would be useful.

I have `ExoPlayer.Listener` which logs me of the player state.

1. When I am streaming I get various states starting from IDLE -> BUFFERING -> READY -> BUFFERING ... so on based on the internet connection or if the media ended ec.
2. When I am playing stored file I only get state IDLE and nothing else happens. I got black screen forever until I `finish()` the activity.

When I tried to play stream file from local storage I did got an `FileNotFound` exception that it cannot find the file, next part of media listed in the stream file. I assume the problem would be in the player setup? Not sure...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a different `RendererBuilder` for a local (video/audio) file.

[`ExtractorRendererBuilder`](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/706c6908ec57005044f4b4a9f5b80266cad9eda3/demo/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer/demo/player/ExtractorRendererBuilder.java) is the thing you should be looking at.

Comment: Yes! Thank you! I already figured it out. Did the same, marking as answer.

Answer (score 1):

As you're using `HlsRendererBuilder` I think you should pass the `.m3u8` playlist file. I'm basing on my experience with `DashRendererBuilder` but I believe `HlsRendererBuilder` works in a very similar way. The Renderer probably is trying to parse a playlist with multiple `.mp4` (or `.ts`) files but you are providing just a `.mp4`file.

Try to download all files listed in your `.m3u8`file including your playlist file and then pass the `URI` like `file:///storage/emulated/0/video/movie.m3u8` to your renderer.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Yes actually you are right. I am aware of that `.m3u8` file is a playlist file. I got to a part where I know that I had to set up a different renderer to be able to render `.mp4` file. I'm giving +1, its a good point.